# Как сохранить картинку с помощью .plist

Tags: xcode, изображения

Доброго времени суток.
Мне нужно сохранить картинку в .plist, вернее даже просто номер её, в проекте у меня 10 картинок, а например в `UIImageView` стои 6-я.

и потом как я буду загружать, чтоб на место `UIImageView` я подгрузил именно 6-ю.

Comment: А почему тогда не воспользоваться NSUserDefaults?
Запись:
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:UIImageViewCodePictures forKey:@"UIImageViewCode"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Ну и вычитка: 
    NSString * string = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"UIImageViewCode"];

Comment: у меня не получаеться. 
-(void)saveDataPic;
{
    NSString *UIImageViewCodePictures;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:UIImageViewCodePictures forKey:@"UIImageViewCode_key"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSLog(@"ввод стринг по ключу=%@",UIImageViewCodePictures);
}
-(void)loadDataPic;
{
    NSString * string = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"UIImageViewCode_key"];
    NSLog(@"вывод стринг по ключу=%@",string);
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [self loadDataPic];
}

при действии выполняю [self saveDataPic];

Comment: 2014-05-08 12:17:54.575 ChangeView01[8836:f803] ввод стринг по ключу=(null)
2014-05-08 12:18:04.446 ChangeView01[8836:f803] вывод стринг по ключу=(null)

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [self loadDataPic];
}